# Getting element of a table with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been having a great experience here so far!

Anyway, in coding my console bot, i encountered a problem. I wish to obtain some text data from a table, this table records a history of input into the site. But his table has no id and only has a class.

so here is the site element codes:

```
<div id="game">
    <div class="gameTop">
        <div class="right">
            <div class="scroll">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>aaa</td>
                            <td>bbb</td>
                            <td>ccc</td>
                            <td>ddd</td>
                        </tr>
```

I wish to get `var xxx = "...."` which corresponds to `ddd`. I have tried `getElementbyClassName('scroll')` but it gives me the table. Which is expected.
I am stuck at how to I delve deeper into the codings.

Comment: You can put an id for your td <td id=ddd> and then getElementbyClassId('ddd')

Comment: Note your HTML is invalid; you're missing the opening quotes on `"gameTop"` and `"scroll"`

Comment: Do you specifically want to get the 4th `td`, or the `td` with `ddd` inside it?

Comment: @Rhumborl i guess he wants the `d`....

Comment: @JorgeMejia Thank you! but the site is not mine, so i don't think i can insert in a elementbyId

Comment: @Rhumborl i would like the 4th td thank you!

Comment: Do you need to select it through the `game` id?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the [`:get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) selector to specifically target the 4th `<td>` element and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to retrieve the content.

```
var dd = $('table td:eq(3)').text();
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/514casyd/1/) with an example.

### Edit

In case you need to get it through `#game`, you can quickly modify the selector to:

```
var dd = $('#game table td:eq(3)').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the table rows as follows:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
var cell = rows[0].cells[4];
var value = cell.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I prefer XPath. See code below:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

var theDddNode = getElementByXpath("//td[contains(text(),'ddd')]");
```